# Exporting data from a dataTable whose ID has been set via a parameter

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, composite-component

I have a composite component that uses a `dataTable` to display data and a `dataExporter`, like this:

The custom component:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="viewModeName" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="data" type="org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="widgetVarName" type="java.lang.String" required="false" default="defaultTableNameWidge"/>
    <composite:attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" required="false" default="defaultTableNameID"/>

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:outputPanel>
                <p:fieldset>
                    <p:dataTable id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
                                 emptyMessage="#{msgs.dataTable_emptyMessage}"
                                 var="myVar"
                                 value="#{cc.attrs.data}"
                                 lazy="true"
                                 rows="20"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 currentPageReportTemplate="({startRecord} - {endRecord} von {totalRecords})"
                                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                 widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.widgetVarName}">

             ... the structure of the table ...

                    </p:dataTable>
                    <div class="footer">
                        <div style="float: right;">

                            <p:commandButton value="Excel-Export" ajax="false" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o" title="someTitle" >
                                <p:dataExporter target="#{cc.attrs.id}" type="xls" postProcessor="#{documentService.postProcessXLS}"
                                    encoding="UTF-8"
                                    fileName="fn"></p:dataExporter>
                            </p:commandButton>

                        </div>
                    </div>
            </p:fieldset>
    </p:outputPanel>
```

As you can see, I set the `id` and `widgetVar` attributes via a parameter that is pass. This is because I use this component twice one the same page, and just using the same static value for `id` and `widgetVar` results in problems.

Here is the page that uses the component twice:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="viewMode" value="#{backendBean.viewMode}"/>
            <f:viewAction action="#{backendBean.init}"  />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:form id="frmTables" styleClass="frmTablesStyle">
    
                <customTableClass:customTable
                        viewModeName = "#{backendBean.viewMode.name()}"
                        data= "#{backendBean.dataAttribute}" />
    
                <c:if test="#{backendBean.viewMode.name() == 'FOREIGN'}">
    
                    <customTableClass:customTable
                            viewModeName = "FOREIGN"
                            data= "#{backendBean.otherDataAttribute}"
                            widgetVarName = "widgetPassedByParameter"
                            id = "idPassedByParameter" />
                </c:if>
    
     </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

This works mostly fine. However, since I changed the id and widgetVar values from static values to setting them via attributes, the `dataExporter` stopped working.

So the `dataExporter` works fine when I have my custom component like this:

```
...
<p:dataTable id="defaultTableNameID" ... />
...
<p:dataExporter target="defaultTableNameID" .../>
```

but not when I have it like this:

```
...
<composite:attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" required="false" default="defaultTableNameID"/>
...
<p:dataTable id="#{cc.attrs.id}" ... />
...
<p:dataExporter target="#{cc.attrs.id}" .../>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Sep 02, 2021 10:57:21 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: Unsupported datasource target:"javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer", exporter must target a PrimeFaces DataTable.
javax.faces.FacesException: Unsupported datasource target:"javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer", exporter must target a PrimeFaces DataTable.
```

How do I properly reference the `id` that I set via parameter from the `target` attribute of the exporter?